# Replace All and reduce text string

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, search, replace, find

I have Google Forms results from live workshops that I want to edit in Sheets. I then want to calculate averages, pivot etc. to explore the data for insights.

I want to clean and standardize the data. I'd like to replace a series of long strings and reduce them just to their leading number:

***UPDATE*** as requested here is a View-only sample Sheet with raw data on 1st tab, and how I'd like it to be formatted (2nd tab)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP8YV3oJXWGt3-88qgzMuup1pm1IsIgD4SHDL09MXrc/edit?usp=sharing

Example:

> 3. I'm aware of certifications I should be starting.

Replace with

> 3

Example 2:

> 4. I'm currently progressing a powerful certification.

Replace with:

> 4

In Excel I would simply use * as wildcard for the rest of the string, but Sheets appears different. I've read documentation and posts about regular expressions etc. and I'm not sure if that's overkill or how to proceed.

I'd THEN like to create a macro which does that for the whole sheet:

```
All strings which begin with 1)*
```

--> Replace with 1

```
All strings which begin with 2)*
```

--> Replace with 2

Comment: What do you mean by replace? Show your input and expected output in sample sheet.

Comment: @cloudchampionsllc Thank you for replying. From `I'd THEN like to create a macro which does that for the whole sheet:`, I had thought that you might want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. But from `Hi, this looks great for my use case. I am able to run the script but I do not see any changes happening in my sheet after.`, I understood that my proposed answer was not useful. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Tanaike you are great, your answer was very clear. I am not familiar with Google Apps Script. Did I follow your instructions correctly? I need a solution which does not require me to manage multiple steps. So if I can easily do this with Apps Script instead of Macro, that would be fine. My columns change and move each time I run this workshop, so Macro is probably not an ideal solution here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had thought that `macro` of `I'd THEN like to create a macro which does that for the whole sheet:` is to use Google Apps Script. This is due to my poor English skill. I really apologize for this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "^\d+")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked inside the sheet which is easy to implement for my skill level.